# pass model property from view to javascript in asp.net MVC5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to asp.net MVC5, please be patient.

I have a controller which returns ActionResult with a model,I can use this model through Razor but I'd like to use it in JavaScript.

I searched for examples and tried then reached to this result

```js
 
   $('document').ready(function () {
   $("#Arrival").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate:userObj , ////here i want to pass model value 
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "img/ui_cal_icon.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select date",

    });
 });
```

this is the script from the view i want to pass this values i got it to maxDate in datepicker

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var userObj = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.MaximumDaysAheadBookable)); //For javascript object
       
    </script>
```

Thanks for help .

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Jasen i want to set the maxdate value in datepicker from model view , you got it ?

Answer (score 1):

Could just be bad naming, but `MaximumDaysAheadBookable` seems like it would be an integer, whereas `maxDate` likely requires a JavaScript date or an ISO date string. If that's the case, then you would need to do something like:

```
 var maxDate = '@DateTime.Today.AddDays(Model.MaximumDaysAheadBookable).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")';
```

It's unnecessary to use `Html.Raw` or `Json.Encode` for this.

Comment: So ,this line i will put it in file.js to pass maxdate to datepicker ?? right

Comment: MaximumDaysAheadBookable class property has max days i set it after 450 days from today this line set it from today ? how i set it dynamically from `Model.MaximumDaysAheadBookable`